# Import JSON data into google sheets as a table

Tags: json, google-sheets

Is there a way to use importJSON() to import this data located here

> http://stats.nba.com/js/data/sportvu/2015/drivesData.json

into Google sheets as a table with formatted rows and columns with headers?

Currently when I use the following, the whole data posts into one cell;

```
=importJSON("http://stats.nba.com/js/data/sportvu/2015/drivesData.json","/resultSets/headers,/resultSets/rowSet","noTruncate,noInherit")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I almost sure that it could be done by script. But here's solution with formulas.

---

**One big formula**

Paste your import formula into cell A1: `=importJSON(...)`. And then paste this formula in Cell A4:

```
={SPLIT(A2,",",0);ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(ArrayFormula(COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,counta(SPLIT(substitute(B2,",,",",-,"),",",0))/COUNTA(SPLIT(A2,",",0)),COUNTA(SPLIT(A2,",",0))))+(row(OFFSET(A1,,,counta(SPLIT(substitute(B2,",,",",-,"),",",0))/COUNTA(SPLIT(A2,",",0))))-1)*counta(SPLIT($A$2,",",0))),{ArrayFormula(COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,counta(split(substitute(B2,",,",",-,"),",",0)))));SPLIT(substitute(B2,",,",",-,"),",",0)},2,0))}
```

It's very big and heavy. There's a way to simplify it.

---

**Step by step formulas**

Here's list of formulas to complete same task.

- A1 -- your formula
- B3 -- `=substitute(B2,",,",",-,")`
- B4 -- `=counta(SPLIT(B3,",",0))`
- B5 -- `=COUNTA(SPLIT(A2,",",0))`
- A7 -- final formula

it will produce the table:

```
={SPLIT(A2,",",0) ;ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(ArrayFormula(COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,B4/B5,COUNTA(SPLIT(A2,",",0))))+(row(OFFSET(A1,,,B4/B5))-1)*counta(SPLIT($A$2,",",0))),{ArrayFormula(COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,B4)));SPLIT(B3,",",0)},2,0))}
```

Ok, it works, not too fast, but it does. Look at [sample workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gcZnrgYPRBxZzMYQn3zxm2jkrTEKIMbbsCMQFYOEais/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I finally got a chance to view this, this works great! Thanks for taking the time to look into this for me Max!